# Go from one if statement to another

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
if (...)                     //enough for promo
{
    if (...)                 //accept offer
    **promo sequence**
    else (...)               //doesn't accept offer (regular purchase)
    **regular sequence**
}
else (...)                   //not enough for promo
**regular sequence**
```

I am still new to programming. I was given a task to write a program inside a loop. The customer gets stamps for purchases. If he has enough stamps, he can have a free item. However, if he denies the offer, it becomes a regular purchase and the number of stamps increases further. I did successfully write the working program (though it is pretty long), and I can paste it here if it helps.

The question is: can I somehow go to regular sequence if the customer does not accept the offer (instead of rewriting the regular sequence)?

Thank you!

Comment: Put the regular sequence inside a function and call it from both places.

Comment: (And for that matter, put the promo sequence inside a function too)

Comment: Yes, you can refactor out the logic to a separate function, then call the function in both else statements.
You could also goto, but that would be a horrible misuse of goto.

Comment: @xyious nah, that's a proper use of goto. This is what goto is still useful for: control flow structures that are not provided by simple branches and loops. Edit: avoiding an unnecessary function call is  a proper use, but as frslm shows, the control flow can be simplified in this case such that neither a function nor goto is needed.

Comment: Can I do it by any other way? I have not studied how to put sequence in a function or use goto. If no, can you give me any hint how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: this is a perfect use case for goto statements :-)

Comment: Oh, @pm100! that's just mean!

Comment: Personally I would never use goto for this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried merging your two if-checks? If you're against creating a function for `promo sequence` and `regular sequence`, you could combine the if-statements' logic into a single, combined check:

```
if (... && ...) //enough for promo and accept offer
    **promo sequence**
else            //not enough for promo or doesn't accept offer (regular purchase)
    **regular sequence**
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. You can turn it into a single if, as frslm suggested.  Sometimes the logic for offering and accepting a promo is too awkward to put into a single if statement.  In that case you can use a bool as a flag that indicates whether the promo was accepted:

```
bool accepted_promo = false;
if (...)                     //enough for promo
{
    ** steps to offer and accept a promo offer **
    if (...)                 //accept offer
    {
        **promo sequence**
        accepted_promo = true;
    }
}

if (!accepted_promo) 
    **regular sequence**
```